# Model's property not being bind to multiselect element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In an `MVC` project I am trying to render a `ListBox` element like so:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    @Html.ListBoxFor(
        model => model.PropertyArray[i],
        Model.SelectList[i],
        new { id = "id_" + i, }
    )
}
```

and the property itself has the following format:

```
private List<int[]> propertyArray
public List<int[]> PropertyArray
{
    get
    {
        var result = new List<int[]>(5);
        // populate data
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        this.propertyArray = value;
    }
}
```

The issue is that `getter` is not being called when loading the model.. If I was to change the property type to `int[]` then that would work well for a single `ListBoxFor` element outside of iteration cycle.

But the idea is to use stacked multi-selects and for that I need a list of some kind (which apparently is not supported?).

I would appreciate to hear out advices about how to bind data to multiple multi-selects from one list, preferably, or alternative solution advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you set the `id` property of the created input elements yourself. Instead, let MVC generate the ids in the format the ModelBinder expects.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PropertyArray[i], Model.SelectList[i])
}
```

Also, why do you need a special getter and setter? Just use the default and initialize the list in the constructor of the ViewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public MyViewModel() {
        PropertyArray = new List<int[]>();
    }

    public List<int[]> PropertyArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this does not work. when you post the model to controller acton -> values from multiselect list are not passed in any way. As I understand - they should be passed in a binded `PropertyArray`. The reason why I need setters and getters is for setting and getting values to and from another property. This is however is not mandatory requirement. As I mentioned - the above solution does not work in my case.

Comment: Are there any working examples on how to retrieve selected values from a list of multiselects in a controller action?